# $3 \times 3 $ Magic Square of Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, magic-square

Below is $3 \times 3$ magic square in which seven of the entries are squared integers, found by Andrew Bremner of Arizona State University (and independently by Lee Sallows of the University of Nijmegen):

$$
\boxed{
\begin{array} {ccc}
373^2 & 289^2 & 565^2 \\
360721 & 425^2 & 23^2 \\
205^2 & 527^2& 222121
\end{array}}$$

What would be an efficient algorithm for finding a new example of a three-by-three magic square with seven squared entries that differs from the one already known ?

I know that general formula$^{(1)}$ for $e_{ij}$ entry of an odd magic square of size $n \times n$ is given by :

$$e_{ij}= n\cdot\left(\left(i+j-1+\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor \right) \bmod n \right)+\left((i+2j-2\right) \bmod n)+1$$

P.S. : Rotations, symmetries, and multiples of this known square don't count as new solutions.

**EDIT**

I have found this one with six squared entries :

$$
\boxed{\begin{array} {ccc}
17^2 & 35^2 & 19^2 \\
697 & 25^2 & 553 \\
889 & 5^2 & 31^2 \end{array}}$$

---

*Remarks:*
$\;^{(1)}$ this formula gives only ***one*** (and special) solution for each size and thus doesn't help for finding various different solutions for a given size (say $3 \times 3$)

Comment: For starters, I think you might want to look for number that are expressible as sums of 3 squares in many (at least 3) different ways.

Comment: @JoelCohen Actually, as sum of 2 squares and then, they have to be compatible to form sums of 3 squares.

Comment: @pedja: Your general formula is only good for finding magic squares containing exactly the numbers $1,2,...,n^2$. It doesn't help here.

Comment: A lot of work has been done on this problem which is surprisingly tricky.  Go to www.muktimagie.com and you will find a square with seven squared entries, which is the current record.  Get one with more that that, or a nontrivial different square that ties it, and you could be drinking French champagne!

Answer (score 7):

You will want to look at [A search for $3\times3$ magic squares having more than six
square integers among their nine distinct integers](http://www.multimagie.com/Search.pdf), by Christian Boyer, and at the papers by Bremner and others that Boyer references. You can't hope to find a new one until you understand the methods used to find the one that's already known.

Boyer also published a paper which I haven't seen: 
Some notes on the magic squares of squares problem, 
Math. Intelligencer 27 (2005), no. 2, 52–64, MR2156534 (2006d:05024).

Answer (score 5):

I've dealt with this some monthes ago and have this in some scribbles. Don't know whether this is of any help.
From the ansatz (where *m* is the horizontal,vertical and diagonal sum):
$$ \begin{array} {rrr|r} & & & m \\ 
    a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & m \\
    d^2 & e^2 & f^2 & m \\
    g^2 & h^2 & i^2 & m \\
\hline
  m&m&m&m
 \end{array} $$
writing this as an array of equations and using Gauss-reduction I arrived at the following magic square with three free parameters $[e,i,h]$ :
$$ \begin{array} {rrr|r} & & & 3e^2 \\ 
    2e^2-i^2       & 2e^2 -h^2& -e^2 +h^2 + i^2 & 3e^2 \\
    -2e^2+h^2+2i^2 & e^2      & 4e^2-h^2-2i^2   & 3e^2 \\
    3e^2-h^2-i^2 & h^2 & i^2 & 3e^2 \\
\hline
  3e^2&3e^2&3e^2&3e^2
 \end{array} $$
If I recall correctly I've seen, that the parameters must be odd and not divisible by $3$ or in other words $e^2,i^2,h^2$ must be congruent $1$ modulo $24$.
I didn't proceed then, however perhaps that representation is of some interest for you.

***[update2]*** Here is one more information which I forgot to include earlier. We can express the conditions on the entries in the magic square, which should also be squares, depending on the three parameters $[e,h,i]$ as a small matrix-multiplication:
$$ \begin{array} {r} 
           &&&&|&e^2| \\
           &&&&|&h^2| \\
           &&&&*|&i^2| \\
          \hline 
 |& 2 & 0 & -1| &   |&a^2| \\
 |& 2 & -1 & 0| &   |&b^2| \\
 |&-1 &  1 & 1| & = |&c^2| \\
 |&-2 &  1 & 2| &   |&d^2| \\
 |& 4 & -1 &-2| &   |&f^2| \\
 |& 3 & -1 &-1| &   |&g^2| \\
 \end{array} $$
I found it much tempting to try to make something out of that structural description to say something about the possibilities for all entries simultanously to be squares, but have not yet a better expression.

---

***[update 1]*** The comments below motivated me to simply try out that parametrized problem. Using a Pari/GP-routine with a three-fold loop for the base-parameters $[e,h,i]$ I got this $7$-squares-solutions in *53* secs (which is also the given $7$-squares solution shown in the thread's initial question):
$$ \small \begin{bmatrix}
      205^2 & 527^2 &  222121 \\
   360721 &  425^2 &       23^2 \\
     373^2 & 289^2&  565^2 
 \end{bmatrix}     
       \small
\begin{bmatrix}
   222121 & 527^2  &     205^2 \\
       23^2 &  425^2 & 360721 \\
    565^2 &  289^2 & 373^2  
 \end{bmatrix} $$

The symmetry of the two solutions indicate, that I could have halved the consumption of time If I had some smarter search-criteria.

With some improved criteria for the loop (*100* sec, $e$ used up to *3000*) I found some more solutions - unfortunately the're only the trivial multiples of the first one... :
$$ \small  \begin{matrix} 
 & a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & d^2 & e^2 & f^2 & g^2 & h2 & i^2 \\
 \hline 
 & 410^2 & 1054^2 & 2^2\cdot 151 \cdot 1471 & 2^2\cdot 137 \cdot 2633 
       & 850^2 & 46^2 & 746^2 & 578^2 & 1130^2 \\ 
 & 615^2 & 1581^2 & 3^2\cdot 151 \cdot 1471  & 3^2\cdot 137 \cdot 2633 
       & 1275^2 & 69^2 & 1119^2 & 867^2 & 1695^2 \\
 & 820^2 & 2108^2 & 4^2\cdot 151 \cdot 1471  & 4^2\cdot 137 \cdot 2633 
       & 1700^2 & 92^2 & 1492^2 & 1156^2 & 2260^2 \\
 & 1025^2 & 2635^2 & 5^2\cdot 151 \cdot 1471  & 5^2\cdot 137 \cdot 2633 
       & 2125^2 & 115^2 & 1865^2 & 1445^2 & 2825^2 \\
 & 1230^2 & 3162^2 & 6^2\cdot 151 \cdot 1471  & 6^2\cdot 137 \cdot 2633
       & 2550^2 & 138^2 & 2238^2 & 1734^2 & 3390^2 \\
 & \vdots \\
 k^2*\ldots&205^2 & 527^2 & 151 \cdot 1471 & 137 \cdot 2633 & 425^2& 23^2 & 373^2 & 289^2 & 565^2\\
& \vdots \end{matrix}
$$

Obviously there is no number $k^2$ which would make the entries in columns $c^2$ and $d^2$ a perfect square, so this scheme cannot provide a better solution for higher $k$.

Here is the Pari/GP-code (updated)

```
isin(x,vgl)=if (x<1,return(1)); for(k=1,#vgl,if(x==vgl[k],return(1)));return(0);

{ listsqsq(max_e=100,max_nosq=3,min_e=1)= local(a,b,c,d ,f,g,  no_sq,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,i2,list,li);
 list=vectorv(20000);li=0;
 for(e=min_e,max_e, e2=e^2;
  for(h=1,ceil(1.5*e),  if(h==e,next()); \\ no higher h needed
        h2=h^2;
        b2=2*e2 - h2; if(isin(b2,[e2,h2]), next()); 
             if(issquare(b2)==0, next()); 
             b=sqrtint(b2);

        for(i=sqrtint(e2-ceil(h2/2)),sqrtint(2*e2-floor(h2/2))+1,  if(isin(i,[e,h,b]),next());  \\ no higher i needed
              i2=i^2;no_sq=0;
              g2=   b2 +e2-i2;  if (isin(g2,[b2,e2,h2,i2])            ,next()); if(issquare(g2)==0,next()); g=sqrtint(g2);
              a2= 2*e2 -i2;     if (isin(a2,[b2,e2,h2,i2,g2])         ,next()); if(issquare(a2)==0,a=-a2;no_sq++, a=sqrtint(a2));
              c2=-e2+h2+i2;     if (isin(c2,[b2,e2,h2,i2,g2,a2])      ,next()); if(issquare(c2)==0,c=-c2;no_sq++, c=sqrtint(c2));
              d2=-2*e2+h2+2*i2; if (isin(d2,[b2,e2,h2,i2,g2,a2,c2])   ,next()); if(issquare(d2)==0,d=-d2;no_sq++, d=sqrtint(d2));
              f2= 4*e2-h2-2*i2; if (isin(f2,[b2,e2,h2,i2,g2,a2,c2,d2]),next()); if(issquare(f2)==0,f=-f2;no_sq++, f=sqrtint(f2));
              if(no_sq>max_nosq,next());
              idx=prime(e)*prime(h)*prime(i)*prime(g);
              li++;list[li]=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,log(idx),no_sq];
            )
      );
    );
   if(li==0  , return(Mat([0])));
   list=Mat(list[1..li]);
   list=vecsort(list~,[10,4,7,8,3,6,7])~;
   return(list);}
```

---

***[update 3]*** An account of the possible *13* primitive solutions (no rotations, no reflections) on behalf of a comment of  @andrewpalfreyman; this is an independent validation of A. Bremner's list:

[image: picture]

I generated this list by computing *all* initial solutions and identifying the occuring coefficients. Duplicate sets of coefficients were ignored, and only $13$ distinct sets of coefficients remained. With this, the according $3 \times 3$-configurations are documented with their first occurences.
Interestingly we have sets of coefficients having only integer values, or half integer etc; my own $7$-squares solutions is here a rotation of configurations *A1*.

Moreover,three primitive rank-deficite initial configurations were as well identified, and I explain the reason for the rank-deficience.

Comment: There exist C(9,3)= 84 possible ways of expressing this reduction. I assume that some are "simpler" than others. Perhaps there's a special one that is the simplest to write down

Comment: There are in fact 16 ways, following Boyer. 9,12,15 are particularly simple (9 is the one above by Gottfried Helms).
2,3,13 have no solution - which is curious.

Comment: Update: just for expanding the informations in that answer, here is a link to a draft on the problem organized around my basic attempts: https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/Helms_2022_magicSquareOfSquares2_draft.pdf

Comment: @AndrewPalfreyman - the cases 2,3,13 are such, that the third entry is completely determined by the other two, which is if *e* and *f* are given, *d* is already determined and gives no new information. The same if *e* and *a* are given, *i* is determined.  The cases 2,3 are of this form. The case 13 is "nicer": the three defining entries given form always a Pell-equation, and by this the third entry is fully determined by the two others.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution. But it's too big to be a comment. I just hope it's useful.

### First observation

You can always arrange the numbers in a magic square so that the smallest is top-middle and the next is bottom-right, then there are two possible arrays of ranks of the $9$ numbers.

```
 TYPE 1        TYPE 0
 8  1  6       8  1  7
 3  5  7  and  4  5  6
 4  9  2       3  9  2
```

The first is itself a magic square, the second is not. The nicest example of a TYPE $0$ magic square is

```
 8   0  7
 4   5  6
 3  10  2
```

### Second Observation

For all magic squares, the sum of the squares of the first row (column) equals the sum of the squares of the last row (column). For example

```
 8² + 0² + 7² = 3² + 10² + 2² = 113
```

So you are not only looking for numbers such that 
$$a+b+c=A+B+C$$

and

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = A^2 + B^2 + C^2$$

you must also have

$$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = A^4 + B^4 + C^4$$

Even further, $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{A,B,C\}$ must both be complete residue systems modulo $3$.