# Do I catch all solutions for the generalized Pell-equation $a^2+b^2 = 2 c^2$ by this matrix-method?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

As one question in a somewhat bigger analysis I want to characterize the set of solutions of the generalized Pell-equation in the title:
$$a^2+b^2 = 2 c^2 \tag 1$$
I'm not much fluent with the Pell-solving technology, and from some initial brute-force solutions I constructed the following scheme, which seems to me as if it could produce all solutions by changing a vector of parameters.
My question is, whether the set of solutions that I find is exhaustive or not - tests in small numbers seem to suggest that.

I introduce two matrices;
$$T= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&3&2\\0&4&3 \end{bmatrix} \tag 2$$
$$C= \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \tag 3$$
The starting solution is the vector $A_0=[a,b,c]=[1,1,1]$.

With this I create further solutions by $$A_k=A_0 \cdot T^k \qquad k \in \mathbb Z \tag {4.1}$$
which gives a list with all solution having $a=1$.
But from each of those solutions one can derive a new initial $A_0$ from where then again a complete list of solutions can be drawn:
$$A_{k_1,k_2,k_3}=A_0 \cdot T^{k_1} \cdot C \cdot T^{k_2}\cdot C \cdot T^{k_3} \tag {4.2}$$
and so on, for arbitrarily many indexes/exponents $k_j$.
Using Pari/GP I implemented a function, which takes the vector of arbitrary length containing the indexes/exponents as argument in the following form
$$  A_x = \operatorname{Pell2Sol}([k_1,k_2,...,k_n]) \tag 5$$
I don't know, whether the resulting structure can be called a tree or whether it has another name.

> Q: As I said above, it seems to me that this indexing of solutions is exhaustive (assuming the number of indexes $n$ is taken from $1$ to $\infty$). Does someone know whether this is true?

<sub>*Context: if this is a valid method, I'll try to extend/adapt it to some similar equations which occur in a combined set of equations in quadratics.*</sub>

---

Here is a simple Pari/GP-implementation:

```
\\ Update: initial vector A0 is configurable to have a gcd-common factor
\\ vector E takes the indexes
\\ env=0 says: give only that solution, 
\\ env=1 says: printout the set of neigboured solutions towards index +- env.
\\ A0 can be configured by a common factor in the function call
{Pell2Sol(E,env=0,gcd=1)=my(A0=gcd*[1,1,1], T=[1,0,0;0,3,2;0,4,3],C=[0,1,0;1,0,0;0,0,1]);
     if(#E==0,return(A0));
     A0*=prod(k=1,#E,C*T^E[k]); 
     if(!env,return(A0));
     return(Mat(vectorv(2*env+1,r,A0 * T^(r-1-env))));}
```

Giving `Pell2Sol([1,0],3)` shows the following sequence of solutions:

```
  a    b    c
 --------------
  7  -601  425
  7  -103   73
  7   -17   13
  7     1    5
  7    23   17
  7   137   97
  7   799  565
```

Here the negative signs should not be significant, since we use the squares anyway. But the signs are significant when computing the lists of solutions using the powers of the matrix ***T*** and the matrix ***C***. I didn't supress the signs here to show that internal effect.

and `Pell2Sol([1,5,1,0],3)` gives

```
     a         b        c
  76793  -5375863  3801697
  76793   -920801   653365
  76793   -148943   118493
  76793     27143    57593
  76793    311801   227065
  76793   1843663  1304797
  76793  10750177  7601717
```

Perhaps a better picture than the two above is the following, (where I also draw the motivating connection to the problem of finding magic squares-of-squares)  (Screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Hi, Gottfried. The primitive null vectors of a ternary quadratic form  can be parametrized  in the same way as Pythagorean triples. Here, $  \left( \frac{a-b}{2} \right)^2   +  \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)^2  = c^2 $    Oh,  in general more than one Pythagorean type formula may be required, see Mordell, Diophantine Equations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples   as well as page 47, Theorem 4 in Mordell

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767109/x2y2-2z2-positive-integer-solutions/1767719#1767719

Comment: Hi, Will! The wikipedia entry has grown much over that version that I roughly remember - this is interesting, thank you for the mmory-refresh! Using the link to cut-the-knot in that aricle I found some more essay, which goes even a step further in details of the matrices, and this looks much familiar in the first view (Lisa Winkler in https://web.archive.org/web/20080516081009/http://www.geocities.com/pythagorean_tuples/) And proceeds also to quadruples, which occurs as well in my eqn.system of quadratics. Something to chew on! :-)

Comment: A minor/trivial objection would be that your method only generated positive numbers, whereas changing the sign of any number in any solution yields another solution. Also $(0,0,0)$ is not generated by this method. Perhaps you could make explicit that you are only considering *positive* integral solutions.

Comment: @Servaes - there occur negative values in all three variables $(a,b,c)$ by selection of the key for the Pell2Sol()-function. If you try some negative values, say `Pell2Sol([-2,-2,0],3)` we should see negative values in $a$ and $b$

Comment: @WillJagy - Sorry I didn't catch the relevance of your first comment; however, tonight the answer of servaes forced me to take a look into that re-expression as pythagorean coordinates. I lately seem to need sometimes a bit stronger trigger, to really see...  (I've put some "preliminary" results as comment at servaes' answer.)

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume that you are only considering *positive* integer solutions $(a,b,c)$, as your method only generates positive integer solutions. You already note that your method preserves $\gcd(a,b,c)$, and so the seed value $(1,1,1)$ can only generated primitive triples. The question then remains whether your method generates *all* primitive triples.

---

First let's characterize all primitive positive integral solutions to your equation. If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers with $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ such that
$$a^2+b^2=2c^2,$$
then as noted in the comments, we must have $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$ and so $x=\frac{a-b}{2}$ and $y=\frac{a+b}{2}$ are integers. They are easily verified be coprime, and if $(a,b,c)\neq(1,1,1)$ then we may interchange $a$ and $b$ if necessary so that $x$ and $y$ are both positive. It is easily verified that
$$x^2+y^2=c^2,$$
meaning that $(x,y,c)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple. Then it is well known that there exist coprime positive integers $m$ and $n$, not both odd and with $m>n$, such that
$$x=m^2-n^2,\qquad y=2mn,\qquad c=m^2+n^2,$$
possibly with the roles of $x$ and $y$ reversed. Conversely, any such choice of $m$ and $n$ yields a primitive Pythagorean triple, and by extension any triple
$$a=m^2+2mn-n^2,\qquad b=n^2+2mn-m^2,\qquad c=m^2+n^2,$$
is a solution to your original equation, and these are all primitive solutions.

---

Next let's consider the solutions generated from the seed $(1,1,1)$ by your method. Because $C^2=I$, the set of all generated solutions has the structure of a binary tree, by generating the two solutions $AT$ and $ATC$ from any previous solution $A$.

From every level of the binary tree to the next, we see that $c\mapsto\ 2b+3c$. This means that for every solution $(a,b,c)$ at the $k$-th level we have $c\geq3^k$, where level $k=0$ corresponds to the seed $A=(1,1,1)$. Because these are levels of a *binary* tree, this shows that your method generates at most $2^{k+1}$ solutions with $c<3^k$.

---

To conclude that your method does not generate *all* primitive solutions,
it now suffices to show that the number of pairs of coprime positive integers $(m,n)$ with $m>n$ that satisfy
$$m^2+n^2<3^k,$$
is greater than $2^{k+1}$. For this fact I refer to [this paper](https://archive.org/details/jstor-2369728/page/n37/mode/2up), that shows as an example application of a more general theorem, that the number of such solutions is asymptotically proportional to $\frac{3^k}{2\pi}$.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it sounds really good! It's night here and I can go through this only tomorrow. Just a short note: Using negative powers of the matrix $T$ we arrive at negative values in $(a,b,c)$ as well. The first surprise when I saw this, that the set of (only) positives $(a,b,c)$ plus the set of absolute values $| (a,b,c)| $ seemed then to give all solutions in positives . I'll look at the paper tomorrow.

Comment: I've looked at the article you've linked to. Whew, that's too much at the moment. But I'll follow your hint about the translation to the pythagorean coordinates $(c,x,y)$. Parallelizing that coordinates as they occur from one of my lists, give a analogon to my $T$ matrix as $U=\small \begin{bmatrix}  3 & 2 & -2 \\  2 & 2 & -1 \\  -2 & -1 & 2  \end{bmatrix}$ . I'll try whether I can find some hint that my tree of lists might be incomplete with regards to the tree of pythagorean triples... Took a long time to catch the proposal for the link to the pythagorean coordinates...(sigh)

Comment: Adding: ah, that $C$ matrix needs a analogon too; the pythagorean version is $D=\small \begin{bmatrix}  1 & . & . \\  . & 1 & . \\  . & . & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, and we can go along with $[1,0,1]\cdot U^{k_1} \cdot D \cdot U^{k_2} \cdot D \cdots U^{k_n}$. So the question can as well be answered when proved or disproved, that the so-created tree of pythagorean coordinates is incomplete. I know the transfer-matrix-representation of the pythagorean triples; the current representation looks indeed somehow different...

Comment: Hmm, I've looked at parallel iterations, say one list in Pell-solutions (with a fixed value in $a$-column) and the parallel list in Pythagorean solutions where I use the transfermatrices ***Pell2Pyth*** and ***Pyth2Pell*** as right multiplicators to change from one format to the other. (This keeps the $c$-column unchanged, the Pell- and Pyth.version have the same $c$-values).  Then I did the opposite way: with each of the 3 iteration matrices for the pythagorean triples I constructed "pyth"-lists and from that using ***Pyth2Pell*** the parallel Pell-lists. (...)

Comment: (...) The resulting Pell-list has a surprising pattern, but still has a constant transfermatrix from one row to the other. But aside of the reordering only familiar looking values occured. For some samples tried anyway I found the needed key for the $Pell2Sol()$ function after some trial&error - this might be refinable. But I came over no observation, which would indicate that any of the pythagorean triples, translated by *Pyth2Pell* into the according Pell-triples could not be decoded by the $Pell2Sol()$ key. So it would be good, if you could any counterexample (...)

Comment: (...) following the arguments around the $ m^2+n^2< 3^k$ idea. Perhaps it is worth here to note, that my method easily generates negatives number in $a$ and/or $b$, so if we take their absolute values only, we have 2 times some values in the range below $3^k$ because the occuring negative and positive numbers have different absolute values except when $a=1$. So if I had something which looks like a counter example, I'd like to try to decode its $Pell2Sol()$-key.

Comment: I'm now getting the idea, how the failure to detect all (primitive) solutions could happen. If we take $D=5$ instead of $D=2$ in $a^2+b^2=D \cdot c^2$ then for $a=22$ I found ***2*** (intervowen) primitive sequences of solutions; only using the third root of the transformation-matrix $T$ one can step from one sublist to the other... It didn't seem that such a thing would happen with $D=2$, but I get now a clue, how the very basic method described in my question could miss complete subtrees. I'll have now to investigate this for the given case with $D=2$ for such an effect.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer
***conjecture***:  No, this method does not catch up *all* solutions.

- By samples of observations: it seems, it only catches only all solutions with no common divisor in $[a,b,c]$.
  If we insert in the function's initialization part instead of $A_0=[1,1,1]$ a multiple like $A_0=17 \cdot [1,1,1]$ , then we get the analogue tree, but with every number triple having that same common divisor.

Remark: the existence of these solutions with common gcd are sometimes nontrivial - in the problem of "magic-squares-of-squares" ("msqosq") we have triples made from some entries with a common divisor and can only be found when $A_0=gcd \cdot [1,1,1]$ is given as starting point. For instance in the only known msqosq with $7$ quadratic entries ($2$ are not squares) there is a triple $[h,b,e]=[-289,527,425]$ which can be found by the proposed function, by changing initialization to $A_0=17 \cdot[1,1,1]$ and then perform `Pell2Sol([-2,-1,1])`.

I have no idea so far, whether this gcd-aspect is the only part that must be introduced into the question's indexing method.

---

***Update***
Triggered by the doubts as user Servaes presented in his/her answer, I tried to find hints, as when the Pythagorean-triple generation rules would construct one triple, which is not/cannot be in the Pell-solution- scheme as described in my question.

The first list is using the first generating-matrix ("WP1") as shown in wikipedia, starting at $A_{py,0}=[1 ,0, 1] $
$$ \begin{array} {l} \text{Pyth WP1 } \to \quad \text{Pell} \\
\small \begin{array} {rrr|rrr}
 x & y & c & a & b & c \\ \hline
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 3 & 4 & 5 & 7 & -1 & 5 \\ 
 5 & 12 & 13 & 17 & -7 & 13 \\ 
 7 & 24 & 25 & 31 & -17 & 25 \\ 
 9 & 40 & 41 & 49 & -31 & 41 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 \end{array} \end{array}
$$

The second list is using the second generating-matrix ("WP2") as shown in wikipedia, again starting at $A_{py,0}=[1 ,0, 1] $

$$ \begin{array} {l} \text{Pyth WP2 } \to \quad \text{Pell} \\
\small \begin{array} {rrr|rrr}
 x & y & c & a & b & c \\ \hline
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 3 & 4 & 5 & 7 & -1 & 5 \\ 
 21 & 20 & 29 & 41 & 1 & 29 \\ 
 119 & 120 & 169 & 239 & -1 & 169 \\ 
 697 & 696 & 985 & 1393 & 1 & 985 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 \end{array} \end{array}
$$

The third list is using the third generating-matrix ("WP3") as shown in wikipedia, now starting at $A_{py,0}=[3 ,4, 5] $. *(A starting triple $[1,0,1]$ runs into a list of zeros)*

$$ \begin{array} {l} \text{Pyth WP3 } \to \quad \text{Pell} \\
\small \begin{array} {rrr|rrr}
 x & y & c & a & b & c \\ \hline
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 3 & 4 & 5 & 7 & -1 & 5 \\ 
 15 & 8 & 17 & 23 & 7 & 17 \\ 
 35 & 12 & 37 & 47 & 23 & 37 \\ 
 63 & 16 & 65 & 79 & 47 & 65 \\ 
 99 & 20 & 101 & 119 & 79 & 101 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
 \end{array} \end{array}
$$

All three Pell-lists look very innocent, and trying some examples from this showed, that all generated Pell-triples could be generated by appropriate keys for the function $Pell2Sol()$

Answer (score 1):

*This answer again does not give a proof or a disprove, but it gives an improvement for the statement of the tree of lists.   (Update Oct 22)*

**Extended / deeper explorations: the parametrizing $(mn)$-list**

Later explorations gave the hint towards the "secret tree behind", in terms of the $[m,n]$ parameters, such that
$$   [a, b,c] = [(m^2-n^2)-2mn, (m^2-n^2)+2mn, m^2+n^2]  \tag 1
$$
$\phantom {asaasasa}$ <sup>*Already given by the answer of user "thissite..." and as well found in other resources like wikipedia*</sup>
$\phantom {asaasasa}$ <sup>*Didn't catch immediately the impact of this parametrization-formula when seen in the answer then.*</sup>

Now since each $(abc)$-triple has a representation *(even generating formula)* by an $(mn)$-triple, each $(abc)$-list has a representation by a $(mn)$-list.
Moreover, the $(mn)$-list has a simple transfer function from $(mn)_k$ to $(mn)_{k+1}$ completely analoguous to that for the $(abc)$-list. This goes by the matrix
$$ U= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\2&1 \end{bmatrix} \tag {2a}$$
and
$$ [m_{k+h},n_{k+h}]=[m_k,n_k] \cdot U^h \tag {2b}$$

By this basic observation the both lists around the roots look like
$$
\left|\small \begin{array} {|c|rrr|rr|l|}
 k& a & b & c & m & n \\ \hline
 \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\\
 -4 & 1 & -239 & 169 & 5 & -12 \\ 
 -3 & -1 & -41 & 29 & -2 & 5 \\ 
 -2 & 1 & -7 & 5 & 1 & -2 \\ 
 -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \text{root-triples}\\ 
 1 & -1 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 41 & 29 & 5 & 2 \\ 
 3 & -1 & 239 & 169 & 12 & 5 \\ 
 4 & 1 & 1393 & 985 & 29 & 12 \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots 
 \end{array} \right| \tag {2c}
$$
where at index $k=0$ there are the resp. root triple/pair $[1,1,1]$ and $[1,0]$.

By the computation of the $(abc)$-list from $(mn)$-list we observe the occurence of alternating signs in the $a$-column. This is a certain inconvenience, since after adapting the transfermatrix $T$ to  $T=\Tiny{\begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0\\0&3&2\\0&4&3\end{bmatrix}}$  we cannot simply work with fractional indexes using fractional powers of $T$ but get complex numbers in the representation of $a$ at that fractional indexes, and this destroys many of the nice patterns occuring by fractional indexes with which I've experimented before. But at the moment I think this is -overall- a more meaningful representation of the lists.

**The transfer between different lists**
We introduce the $(mn)$-list-to-list transfermatrix $$ D=\small \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} \tag {3a}$$

In spite of the now occuring alternating signs in the $a_k$ values in *(2c)*, we do not need to adapt $(abc)$-list-to-list transfermatrix $C$. It is still:
$$ C= \small \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}\tag{3b}$$

**The general construction formula for creation of the full tree**
Now we can, as written in the OP, give a transformation-formula for the $(abc)$-triple from one to another:
$$ \operatorname{ABC}(\text{abc},\text{Key})= \text{abc} \cdot T^{h_1} \cdot C \cdot T^{h_2} \cdot C \cdot \ldots \cdot C \cdot T^{h_n} \tag {4a}$$
where **Key** is a vector of given exponents for the concatenating of $T$-matrix-multiplications like $ \text{Key} = [h_1,h_2,...,h_n] $.

Completely parallel we define the transformation-formula for the $(mn)$-tree
$$ \operatorname{MN}(\text{mn},\text{Key})= \text{mn} \cdot U^{h_1} \cdot D \cdot U^{h_2} \cdot D \cdot \ldots \cdot D \cdot U^{h_n} \tag{4b} $$

and the generation-formulae for the elements of the full trees are simple application of those formulae when the root-triples $[a,b,c]=[1,1,1]$ resp $[m,n]=[1,0]$ are provided by default:
$$ \operatorname{ABC0}(\text{Key}) =\operatorname{ABC}([1,1,1],\text{Key})  \\ 
\operatorname{MN0}(\text{Key}) =\operatorname{MN}([1,0],\text{Key}) \tag 5 $$

---

**Conclusion**

- So far, this is only an update for/improvement of the original proposal in the OP; I still have to hope for a ***proof***, that such a rooted tree covers ***all*** possible primitive solutions for the generalized Pell's equation $a^2+b^2=2c^2$, although it is not only an infinite tree, but even an "infinitary" tree - meaning each node has infinitely many children (in contrast to -say- the infinite "binary" tree, where each node has two children).

---

**Some additional notes which I think are important.**

- I want to make clear, that all solution-triples in the tree have no common divisor for $(abc)$ in a triple. Instead, we've to be aware, that there exist infinitely many parallel such trees, characterized by the root $(abc)=[1,1,1] \cdot g$ where $g$ is then the common divisor for ***all*** triples in the tree.
- The nice format of each $(abc)$-list was misleading me into the assumption, that as well each such $(abc)$-list provides the full set of solutions with a fixed parameter $a$ *(although I should have known better from my initial heuristics!)*. But this is not always the case. There are (likely infinitely many) cases where $(abc)$-lists with same $a$-parameter exist, for example:
  $$\left| \Tiny { \begin{array} {c|rrr|rrr}
   k & a&b&c & a&b&c \\ \hline 
   \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
  -3& -119 & -6319 & 4469 & -119 & -16519 & 11681 \\ 
  -2& 119 & -1081 & 769 & 119 & -2833 & 2005 \\ 
  -1& -119 & -167 & 145 & -119 & -479 & 349 \\ 
  0& 119 & 79 & 101 & 119 & -41 & 89 \\ 
  1& -119 & 641 & 461 & -119 & 233 & 185 \\ 
  2& 119 & 3767 & 2665 & 119 & 1439 & 1021 \\ 
  3& -119 & 21961 & 15529 & -119 & 8401 & 5941 \\
   \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
   \end{array} } \right|  \tag 6
  $$
  The column-centers at $k=0$ ($(abc)_0$) have the keys $\text{Key1}=[1, -1, 1, -1, 1,0]$ and $\text{Key2}= [2, 1,0]$, whose bare co-existence also shows, that that two lists belong to the same $(abc)$-tree, rooted at the $(abc)_0=[a,b,c]_0=[1,1,1]$-triple.
- For error check, but as well as general tool, there is a simple rule, with which we can show, that some given $(abc)$-triple is a member of the $[1,1,1]$-rooted $(abc)$-tree. I've not yet the proof of the validity of this rule, but so far no error occured.
- The idea with this all was to possibly find easier specific (or all) solutions of systems of multiple such Pell-equations, say for instance ($[a,b,x]$,$[a,c,y]$,$[b,c,z]$) which occur when $a^2+b^2-c^2=x^2$,$a^2-b^2+c^2=y^2$,$-a^2+b^2+c^2=z^2$ is considered (as recently in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4546172)), or when multiple Pell equations of this form occur in the analysis of magic squares of squares ([MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/175762/1714) or [this](https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/Helms_2022_magicSquareOfSquares2_draft.pdf)). However, my search routines for such coupled Pell-equations based on this tree-structure are not yet satisfying, possibly they shall come out not better than naive search algorithms running over multiple loops... Don't see any real progress at the moment...